# 64-bit SciPy.FFTPack for Windows?

Tags: python, windows, scipy, fftpack

I used to have `scipy.fftpack` available on 32-bit Python 2.7, but now that I upgraded to 64-bit Python and got SciPy from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy), I noticed it doesn't seem to include FFTPack.

Where can I download it?

Oh, and the error is:

```
>>> import scipy.fftpack
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 2.7\lib\site-packages\scipy\fftpack\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from basic import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 2.7\lib\site-packages\scipy\fftpack\basic.py", line 11, in <module>
    import _fftpack
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

Comment: That build of scipy requires [Numpy-MKL](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy), which includes the Intel runtime libraries.

Comment: @cgohlke: :( do you happen to know of any other build that doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, ProcMon helped me finally figure it out.

It turns out that that version *does* include FFTPack, but does *not* include `libmmd.dll`, which seems to (?) be part of Intel's Math Kernel Library.

If you have the library available in your PATH then it should indeed work.